Looking for monitor that looks like HP E233
I have 3 of HP E233 monitors currently and I am shifting countries. The belongings will take 6 to 9 weeks to get there.  I will carry my motherboard with me.  I am planning to buy a case and a monitor so I can carry on working.
Is there a newer version of HP 233 with the same dimensions and looks ?  I can then have 4 monitors on a mount.

The HP E243 might be an option. This monitor has the looks of an E233 but is .8 inch larger, but with this monitor you most likely get the same color displayed. Another option might be the HP E23 G4 monitor, this monitor is the same size but also more likely to have different color displayed.

I have accepted it as an answer, but you can improve it by posting a link to it.

Also +1 because it takes a lot of time to compare them.
